# How do I use ffmpeg to mix an audio/video file with an audio file with an offset?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mixing

I have two media files that I want to combine using ffmpeg.

1. File 1 contains audio and video and starts at time = 0 sec.
2. File 2 contains contains audio only, and the start of this file is at time = 2.5 sec.

How do I use ffmpeg to combine these files, with the audio file properly offset?

This is what I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i video_and_audio.webm -itsoffset 2.5 -i audio_only.webm -filter_complex amix out.webm
```

This results in an audio/video file with that appears to have the correct length, and with the audio from both files mixed, but the audio is not offset properly from the audio-only file. The audio-only file appears to start time=0, as if there were no itsoffset argument. I have also tried other values after itsoffset, thinking the units might not actually be seconds. Even with a value of 2500, the audio-only file still seems to start immediately.

ffmpeg output appears to be commonly requested:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (SUSE Linux)
  configuration: --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-debug --disable-stripping --extra-cflags='-fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g' --enable-pic --optflags='-fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g' --enable-gpl --enable-x11grab --enable-version3 --enable-pthreads --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --enable-avfilter --enable-libpulse --enable-libwebp --enable-libvpx --enable-libopus --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-postproc --enable-libdc1394 --enable-librtmp --enable-libfreetype --enable-avresample --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --disable-decoder=dca --enable-libdcadec --enable-frei0r --enable-libcelt --enable-libcdio --enable-ladspa
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'video_and_audio.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.5.91
    creation_time   : 2015-11-23 02:57:26
  Duration: 00:01:20.78, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 323 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 480x640, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'audio_only.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.5.91
    creation_time   : 2015-11-23 02:58:46
  Duration: 00:01:17.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 79 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
[libopus @ 0x16c3320] No bit rate set. Defaulting to 96000 bps.
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x16bd800] v1.3.0
Output #0, webm, to 'out.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus (libopus), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libopus
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vp9 (libvpx-vp9), yuv420p, 480x640 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4], q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 1k fps, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libvpx-vp9
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (vorbis) -> amix:input0 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (vorbis) -> amix:input1 (graph 0)
  amix (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libopus)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (vp8 (native) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:480x640 fmt:yuv420p to size:360x480 fmt:yuv420p
[libopus @ 0x16c3320] Queue input is backward in time30.41 bitrate= 265.3kbits/s    
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:360x480 fmt:yuv420p to size:240x320 fmt:yuv420p
[libopus @ 0x16c3320] Queue input is backward in time00.28 bitrate= 254.3kbits/s    
frame= 1077 fps=4.9 q=0.0 Lsize=    2433kB time=00:01:20.79 bitrate= 246.7kbits/s    
video:1660kB audio:738kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.456821%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have successfully used the `adelay` filter to do this.  Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg \
    -i video_and_audio.webm \
    -i audio_only.webm \
    -c:v copy \
    -filter_complex '[1:a] adelay=2500|2500 [delayed]; [0:a] [delayed] amix [out]' \
    -map 0:v \
    -map '[out]' \
    out.webm
```

Note that when using the `adelay` filter, the delay must be specified in milliseconds and must be specified individually for each audio channel. In this example, the audio is stereo (2-channel) so the delay is specified twice.

Line by line explanation:

- first input file
- second input file
- copy video directly to output without any changes
- complex filter which takes the audio of the second input, delays it, and then mixes that with the audio of the first input
- selects the video stream from the first file to output
- selects the mixed audio stream to output
- output file name

You may not actually need the `-map` lines, but I prefer to use them.

Comment: Another way to do it - by concatenating silence on the beginning - is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31957317/829970), but I think this way is more elegant.